# How i can return to my template a value based in a typescript decision?

Tags: angular

I have one service that returns an JSON with a property called `name`.

I'm doing a `*ngFor` in this JSON in my template and based in the `name` property, i need to show a specific material icon.

I tried to create a function `getIcon()` that receives the name and return the specific icon:

**TS:**

```
getIcon(name: string): string {
   if (name === 'h01') {
      return 'home'
   }
   else if (name === 'c30') {
       return 'clipboard'
   }
}
```

**Template:**

```
 <mat-icon aria-hidden="false">{{ getIcon(myJson.name) }}</mat-icon>
```

But everytime that i do one action in my screen, e.g click in a button, this function is called again several times, so, i'm searching if have a better way to do this.

Comment: https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496#:~:text=Because%20expression%20are%20so%20powerful,our%20views%20become%20more%20complex.&text=While%20function%20calls%20in%20Angular,may%20cause%20serious%20performance%20issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem using Angular [pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

**src/app/pipes/icon-name.ts**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'iconName',
  pure: false // detect object change
})
export class IconNamePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, fallback: string = ''): string {
    if (name === 'h01') {
      return 'home';
    }
    else if (name === 'c30') {
       return 'clipboard';
    }
    return fallback;
  }
}
```

**template**

```html
 <mat-icon aria-hidden="false">{{ myJson.name | iconName: 'default-icon' }}</mat-icon>
```